# Django how to store data as global table

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to Django and got a question. So I currently use pandas.read_sql_query to query data from the database (MSSQL), I don't create the model because it's the company's database and I don't think I can do this. Please correct me if I am wrong, I may don't fully understand what model does.

The table I need requires multiple query and do some data cleaning/table merge with pandas which cost over 10mins. Most of the time spend on query the data from the database.

(1) Is there a way to query the data and then store it in Django somewhere as a global table? So it will save a lot of time and the table can be reused.
(2) If yes, can I setting sometime to update the global data table as specific frequerncy?

Thank you so much and any help is really apprecaited!